# Visual Tree (graph) generating

Tags: tree, graph, generator

I'm trying to find a piece of software or some API / technology that would allow me to do the following....

I'm looking to generate a family tree based on input I was to feed into a piece of software. I'd like each child of the tree to be clickable and for me to embed it into a website somehow.

Comment: sounds like an interesting project to explore with HTML5 canvas element...

Comment: @Russ not a bad idea! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think AT&T's graphviz is a great tool for displaying trees.

[This link](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/FAQ.html) suggests that it's possible to associate a URL with a node: "...Note that URL tags are respected, to allow clickable PDF objects..."

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Ryan Schmidt's [Canviz](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/) parser for Graphviz output. It takes the xdot output you'd get from running Graphviz on a server and renders it using pure Javascript.